# Programmatically add and edit controls

Tags: c#, wpf

I create programmatically an WPF TabItem and added it to my TabControl.

```
   var tabItem = new TabItem { Header = "foo" };
```

Now I want to do something like

```
   var txt1 = new TextBlock { Text = "foo" };
   var txt2 = new TextBlock { Text = "bar" };

   var tabItem = new TabItem { Header = txt1 + txt2 }; // cannot apply operator + to TextBlock and TextBlock
   // Other Idea:
   // var tabItem = new TabItem { Header = new TextBlock { Text = "foo" }.Text + new TextBlock { Name = "txt2", Text = "bar" }};
   // Maybe I could edit my TextBlock via it's name?
   ...
   txt2.Text = "editedBar"; // have to update the header of tabItem.
```

Is this anyway possible? I know in XAML it wouldn't be a problem. But the existing architecture forces me to try this way.

Comment: To clarify, when `txt2.Text = "editedBar";` runs, the header should update to `fooeditedBar`?

Comment: I cannot imagine of an "existing architecture" where you cannot create a proper UserControl or otherwise XAML-defined UI (which is the right way to do it), and then in any case add that to an existing stuff procedurally.

Comment: Where are these values of `txt1` and `txt2` coming from? If they're two properties in the same scope, an easy solution would be to create a third property that combines the two. (`public string MyProp { get { return Prop1 + Prop2; } }`) I'm having trouble imagining a scenario where you'd want to display them mashed together like that, especially if they're not closely linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
panel.Children.Add(txt1);
panel.Children.Add(txt2);

var tabItem = new TabItem { Header = panel };
```

Comment: This worked for me. But I have to set the header each time. `tabItem.Header = stackPanel`. `txt2 = "foo"` isnt enough.

Comment: There's no need to set the Header each time.  You should access the TextBlocks like this ((TextBlock)(StackPanel)tabItem.Header).Children[0]).Text = "foo";  It's a little busy :(

Answer (score 0):

The OP asked for a programmatical way to create WPF `TabItems` and add to the `TabControl`, through the adding of `UserControls`, but if you have a `List` or `Collection` of your objects, you can bind them to the `TabControl.ItemsSource` then use  `DataTemplates` to specify the `ItemTemplate` and `ContentTemplate`.

TabControl XAML:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} {0}{1}">
                    <Binding Path="HeaderA"/>
                    <Binding Path="HeaderB"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock>
            <TextBlock.Text>
            <Binding Path="MyContent"/>
            </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

*MyItem* class being used for TabControl

```
public class MyItem {
    public string HeaderA { get; set; }
    public string HeaderB { get; set; }
    public string MyContent { get; set; }
}
```

List of *MyItem* objects

```
public List<MyItem> MyItems {
    get {
        return new List<MyItem>() {
            new MyItem() { 
                HeaderA = "Foo0", 
                HeaderB = "Bar0", 
                MyContent = "This is content."
            },
            new MyItem() { 
                HeaderA = "Foo1",
                HeaderB = "Bar1",
                MyContent = "This is content."}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can change *MyContent* into an `object` class, then use `DataTemplates` with the `DataType` attribute to specify what to show in ContentTemplate if they you have different objects for your content.